# recoding categorical with no mapping values

Tags: r

Got a data frame with a lot of variables (82), many of them are used for further calculations. So I've tried to convert to numerical but there's a huge work guessing distinct values for every variable and then assign numbers.

I wonder if there's a more automated way of doing it since I don't care which number is assigned to any value as it is not repeated.

My approach so far (for he sake of clarity, dummy data):

```
df <- data.frame(original.var1 = c("display","memory","software","display","disk","memory"),
original.var2 = c("skeptic","believer","believer","believer","skeptic","believer"),
original.var3 = c("round","square","triangle","cube","sphere","hexagon"),
original.var4 = c(10,20,30,40,50,60))
```

taking into account this worked fine

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

     df$NEW1 <- as.numeric(interaction(df$original.var1, drop=TRUE))
```

I've tried to adapt to dplyr and pipes this way

```
 df %<>% mutate(VAR1= as.numeric(interaction(original.var1, drop=TRUE))) %>%
            mutate(VAR2= as.numeric(interaction(original.var2, drop=TRUE))) %>%
            mutate(VAR3= as.numeric(interaction(original.var2, drop=TRUE)))
```

but results got wrong from third VAR ahead

```
 df %>% dplyr::group_by(original.var1,VAR1) %>% tally()
    # A tibble: 4 x 3
    # Groups:   original.var1 [?]
      original.var1  VAR1     n
             <fctr> <dbl> <int>
    1          disk     1     1
    2       display     2     2
    3        memory     3     2
    4      software     4     1

    > df %>% dplyr::group_by(original.var2,VAR2) %>% tally()
    # A tibble: 2 x 3
    # Groups:   original.var2 [?]
      original.var2  VAR2     n
             <fctr> <dbl> <int>
    1      believer     1     4
    2       skeptic     2     2

    > df %>% dplyr::group_by(original.var3,VAR3) %>% tally()
    # A tibble: 6 x 3
    # Groups:   original.var3 [?]
      original.var3  VAR3     n
             <fctr> <dbl> <int>
    1          cube     1     1
    2       hexagon     1     1
    3         round     2     1
    4        sphere     2     1
    5        square     1     1
    6      triangle     1     1
```

Any approach or package to recode not having the mapping declared previously?

Comment: Effectively, are you looking for this? `sapply(df, function(i) as.numeric(interaction(i, drop = TRUE)))`... or in `dplyr` `df %>% mutate_all(funs(as.numeric(interaction(., drop = TRUE))))`

Comment: Good approach Sotos , but not all columns are needed to process this way. Some of them are numerical

Comment: You should give a sample that takes into account all of your cases

Comment: added a fourth Numerical column. No need to recode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mutate_if`,

```
library(dplyr)

mutate_if(df, is.factor, funs(as.numeric(interaction(., drop = TRUE))))
```

which gives,

> ```
>   original.var1 original.var2 original.var3 original.var4
> 1             2             2             3            10
> 2             3             1             5            20
> 3             4             1             6            30
> 4             2             1             1            40
> 5             1             2             4            50
> 6             3             1             2            60
> ```

Alternatively you can read your data frame with `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` and use `is.character` but it's the same thing

To address your comment, If you want to also keep your original columns, then,

```
mutate_if(df, is.factor, funs(new = as.numeric(interaction(., drop = TRUE))))
```

Comment: just a bit more: preserving original columns ? take into account that after all stats are done we want to know the original values

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: oh my! This is great. Much better than my purrr approach

Answer (score 1):

Using purrr Keep the factor columns only and operate on them. Merge with numerical at the end.

```
df %>% purrr::keep(is.factor) %>% mutate_all(funs(as.numeric(interaction(., drop = TRUE))))
```

Comment: Be very careful. not working with my real data. Using this very same code all I get is  1,1,1,1,1,1,1